# Register ActiveX control in 64 bit windows

Tags: 64-bit, activex

I have an ActiveX control, I try to register it in windows 7 64 bit and gives me the following error:

"The Module MtnControl.dll faild to load. Make sure the the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files"

I am Registering the Control using Command Prompt.
**Note:** I can register the control on 32 bit windows.
**Note:** I've tried to put the .DLL file in SysWow64 folder and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 64bits, putting your 32bits ActiveX in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` is a good point. Then register your component with `regsvr32` located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (32bits version).

Doing that, do you have still an error? In the affirmative, maybe you ActiveX depends on other DLL which could not be found!